# block with position: fixed begins to swim with a scroll with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: html, ios, css

on the iPhone iOS when adding -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; the title of the menu with position: fixed; begins to swim with a scroll. The header is in the modal window, which also has the same position: fixed; How can I fix this?

[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li48N0iy29Q)

Comment: better to include your code here

Comment: As far as I know, elements can't swim, you throw them in the deep end and they will drown, unless they `float`.